# Explain the output of this program of this code?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

// Explain the output of this code,specifically can't understand the last printf output...Please explain

```
int a1[]={6,7,8,18,34,67};
int a2[]={23,56,28,29};
int a3[]={-21,27,-31};
int *x[]={a1,a2,a3};

void print(int *a[])
{
    printf("%d",a[0][2]); // outputs 8
    printf("%d",*a[2]); //outputs -21
    printf("%d",*++a[0]); //outputs 7
    printf("%d",*(++a)[0]); //outputs 23
    printf("%d",a[-1][+1]); /*outputs 8  explain?*/

}

 main()
{
   print(x);
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Why is it confusing?

Comment: Note the position of `a` after increment operations and the negative index might be confusing but it if fine unless it does not access out of bound index. _Note  : index is not applied to array `a1`, `a2` , `a3` but to array of pointers_.

Comment: please explain `1-1+sqrt(45*45)-45` This code is just a sunday morning experiment. Not really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that a is a pointer to a pointer and may be changed, it isn't the same object as the array x, it merely points to the first element of that array. The same holds for the elements of array x: x[0], x[1], and x[2] are pointers to first elements of arrays a1, a2, a3.

Before the last printf line, the pointer a points to the second element of the array x, which is a pointer to the array a2. The cause for this is the fourth printf line which incremented the pointer a by one.

Then we step into the last printf line.

The first subscript `[-1]` decrements the pointer a, the result now points to the first element of the array x, which is a pointer to the array a1. The dereference gives the value of that pointer. Because of the third printf line, this pointer points to the second element of the array a1.

The second subscript `[1]` retrieves the the third element of array a1.